# rbindlist list length and performance

Tags: r, elasticsearch, data.table

I'm running a script to a download large amounts of data from an Elastic Search Database, and am wondering what's the most efficient way to combine this data that comes split into single dataframes.

I'm using rbindlist and noticed that there seems to be a 'sweet spot' between the length of the list to be bound (that is, the number of data.tables bound at once) and the total amount off data. On the one hand I'm trying to avoid growing the list of data.tables too long, since that has a detrimental impact on performance. On the other hand side, too short a list of data.tables lets the target data.table grow incrementally and inefficiently. For test data with around 130.000 entries, the best result I got (via trial and error in the list length) was to download and combine all data within 11 minutes, binding 1.000 data.tables at once. The downloaded data comes in batches of 10 rows per frame (via the Elastic Search scrolled search), so we're talking 13.000 dataframes combined in total. Not batching the binding (that is, putting all 13.000 dataframes into one list and combining them in the end) took about 13 minutes, including downloads.

Since the full data that might eventually get downloaded at once is currently at ~24 mio entries and counting, I'm very much interested in making this process as efficient as poosible.

Since access to the Elastic Search Data is restricted, I cannot share any real data. The data.frames that are being bound are small, with ~10 rows and 9 columns. Rownumbers can vary per call (e.g. when the end of the search is reached) and the number of columns depends on the requested data. Let me know if you need more information on the data processed, I can try to whip up an example then. Here is the code I'm currently running (minus a few improvements, like the progress package's progress_bar to show progress and the number of currently downloaded files, which are not important here):

```
res <- Search(conn, asdf = T, body = body, time_scroll = time_scroll)
out <- res$hits$hits
hits <- 1

list <- list()
list_length = 1000

while (hits != 0) {                                               # keep going while there are still more results from the Search
        res <- scroll(conn = conn, x = res$`_scroll_id`, asdf = T)
        
        hits <- length(res$hits$hits)
        
        if (hits > 0) {
                list[length(list)+1] <- list(res$hits$hits)        # make list of results to bind later
        }

        if (length(list)==list_length) {                           # bind results every x calls (~10 datapoints per call)
                  out <- rbindlist(c(list(out), list), fill = T)
                  list <- list()
        }
        
        if (length(list) <= list_length & hits == 0) {             # bind leftovers
                  out <- rbindlist(c(list(out), list), fill = T)
                  list <- list()
        }
}
```

So my question is two-fold:

1. Does anybody have any experience with the ratio of list length to total amount of data when binding dataframes with rbindlist() for very large amounts of data? My assumption is that this ratio changes the larger the data gets, so any experience (and maybe even fixed ratios!) would be very welcome.
2. Regarding this specific code, are there ways to speed it up? Since the total number of rows for the final data.table is known (Elastic gives the total number of hits), I was thinking it may be an option to preallocate the size of the final data.table. However, I do not know how to implement such a preallocation into the above code, or if this is necessary when using rbindlist.

Comment: I've realized that one way to significantly speed up the data collection is to set the number of the search results up to 10.000 (size argument in Search). Much to my surprise, this does not hit rate limits immediately. However, my main question remains and concerns the rbindlist() argument: how to balance list length against total amounts of data and/or preallocate data sizes in  this case?

Answer (score 0):

I've done some testing with preallocations. It seems to significantly slow down the more the data.frame gets filled up. So rbindlist() seems superior to preallocating data. Either that or my preallocation code is inefficient.

Code:

```
  # initial search, sets query
  res <- Search(conn, asdf = T, size = size, body = body, time_scroll = time_scroll)

  # preallocate rows of data.frame
  out <- res$hits$hits
  out[nrow(out) + (total - nrow(res$hits$hits)),] <- NA    

  hits <- 1

    while (hits != 0) {

      res <- scroll(conn = conn, x = res$`_scroll_id`, asdf = T)

      hits <- length(res$hits$hits)
      
      out[(nrow(out[!is.na(out$"_id"),])+1):(nrow(out[!is.na(out$"_id"),]) + nrow(res$hits$hits)),] <- res$hits$hits     # add results

    }
```